# Zend Framework 2 - how to use form helpers in layout.phtml

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'm trying to put my login form in the header which resides within layout.phtml

I've created my form object in Application/Module.php

```
<?php
namespace Application;

use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

use Users\Form\LoginForm;

class Module
{
  public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
  {
    .
    .
    .
    $form = new LoginForm();

    $form->get('submit')->setValue('Login');

    $application = $e->getParam('application');
    $viewModel = $application->getMvcEvent()->getViewModel();
    $viewModel->form = $form;
  }
.
.
.
}
```

This is so that the form is available for every page (as layout.phtml is used to render every page)

For my layout.phtml file:

```
<?php echo $this->doctype(); ?>

<?php 

$form = $this->layout()->form;

//\Zend\Debug\Debug::dump($form);

$form->prepare();

$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url(NULL, array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login')));

?>

<html>
<head>

<?php echo $this->headTitle('Budget') ?>

<?php echo $this->headMeta()
->appendName('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1')
->appendHttpEquiv('X-UA-Compatible', 'IE=edge') ?>

<?php echo $this->headLink(array('rel' => 'shortcut icon', 'type' => 'image/vnd.microsoft.icon', 'href' => $this->basePath() . '/img/favicon.ico'))
->prependStylesheet($this->basePath() . '/css/style.css')
->prependStylesheet($this->basePath() . '/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css')
->prependStylesheet($this->basePath() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css') ?>

</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<a href="/liftshare/" class="navbar-brand">Lift share</a></div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li><a href="/liftshare/search">Search</a></li>
<li><a href="/liftshare/offers">Offer a lift</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

<?php echo $this->form()
->setAttribute('class', 'navbar-form')
->setAttribute('role', 'form')
->openTag($form); ?>

<div class="form-group">
<?php echo $this->formLabel($form->get('email')
->setLabelAttributes(array('id' => 'login_email'))
->setLabelAttributes(array('class' => 'sr-only'))
->setLabelAttributes(array('placeholder' => 'Enter email'))
); ?>
<input class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Enter email" type="email">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">Password</label>
<input class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Password" type="password">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>

<?php echo $this->form()->closeTag(); ?>

</ul></div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div>
</nav>
</div>

<?php echo $this->content; ?>

<?php echo $this->inlineScript() ?>

<!-- Scripts -->
<?php echo $this->headScript()
->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js')
->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/jquery.min.js')
->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/respond.min.js', 'text/javascript', array('conditional' => 'lt IE 9',))
->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/html5shiv.js','text/javascript', array('conditional' => 'lt IE 9',))
; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm getting the error - `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend\Form\View\Helper\Form::setAttribute() in /var/www/budget_zend/module/Application/view/layout/layout.phtml on line 55`

I understand that the form helpers that were available in my other views are perhaps not available in the layout view. But how do I put a form in the layout.phtml file then? Also, seems a bit strange that I have to define this in different ways - say, for example, I at some point want to move the form from the header (within the layout.phtml file) to the main content area - this means I need to change stuff at the backend to make a front end update. Doesn't seem right. Can someone please inform me how I should be doing things.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand that the form helpers that were available in my other views are perhaps not available in the layout view

This is not the case. Layouts and views can access exactly the same view helpers.

I think you are confusing the form view helper (`$this->form()`) with the instance of your Login form (`$this->form`, or `$form` since you've assigned it to that variable). The form *view helper* doesn't have a `setAttribute()` method, hence the error.  You probably mean something more like this:

```
$form->setAttribute('class', 'navbar-form')
     ->setAttribute('role', 'form');

echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's cleaner to write a custom view helper then assigning the Form trough the bootstrap event every time.

Assuming you'd place the ViewHelper php file in `Application/src/View/YourFormHelper.php` you would need to configure it within the `module_config.php` like so:

```
'view_helpers' => array(
    'invokables'=> array(
        'yourFormHelper' => 'Application\View\Helper\YourFormHelper',
    ),
),
```

If your Form requires a service you might asweel want to create a factory which inject's those rather then just having a invokable without dependencies.

Within your View Helper just configure your forms as usual. But keep in mind You'll need to extend the `AbstractHelper` and implement the `__invoke()` method.

```
namespace Application\View\Helper;

use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class PageChunk extends AbstractHelper
{   

    public function __invoke()
    {        
       //build form and add elements/inputfilters
       return $form;
    }
}
```

You now could implement some kind of rendering so It would just return the form html tag's etc.

For explanatory reasons we'll just attach the form in our layout like so and the form should be displayed in the layout correctly.

```
// within your layout.phtml
...
$form = $this->yourFormHelper();
...
// open tag/close tag, formRow etc
```